# Can an Action/delegate change it's arguments value?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, extension-methods, anonymous-function

I ran into what was to me an unexpected result when testing a simple `ForEach` extension method.

`ForEach` method

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Action<T> action)
{
    if (action == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("action");

    foreach (T element in list)
    {
        action(element);
    }
}
```

`Test` method

```
[TestMethod]
public void BasicForEachTest()
{
    int[] numbers = new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    numbers.ForEach(num =>
    {
        num = 0;
    });

    Assert.AreEqual(0, numbers.Sum());
}
```

Why would `numbers.Sum()` be equal to 55 and not 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`num` is the copy of the value of the current element you are iterating over. So you are just changing the copy.

What you do is basically this:

```
foreach(int num in numbers)
{
     num = 0;
}
```

Surely you do not expect this to change the content of the array?

**Edit**: What you want is this:

```
for (int i in numbers.Length)
{
     numbers[i] = 0;
}
```

In your specific case you could maintain an index in your `ForEach` extension method and pass that as second argument to the action and then use it like this:

```
numbers.ForEachWithIndex((num, index) => numbers[index] = 0);
```

However in general: Creating Linq style extension methods which modify the collection they are applied to are bad style (IMO). If you write an extension method which cannot be applied to an `IEnumerable<T>` you should really think hard about it if you really need it (especially when you write with the intention of modifying the collection). You have not much to gain but much to loose (like unexpected side effects). I'm sure there are exceptions but I stick to that rule and it has served me well.

Comment: I agree what I want is a for loop, but how would I make it work in an extension method if the argument is passed by value when the call to action is made?  It doesn't look like there is a way to pass the value by reference to the action delegate that is passed to the ForEach function.  I guess everyone knows it, but I did not realize that foreach(int num in numbers){ num = 0; } would not work.  Why is num a temporary copy and not a reference?  I kind of assumed that foreach was just syntactic sugar for "for".  I guess I need to stop making so many assumptions.

Comment: I'd like to figure out some way to write that ForEach extension so that it can change the value of an int.  I don't guess that makes sense, but it's a puzzle I'd like to solve.

Comment: The addition of the ForEachWithIndex makes since.  I was wrong about how things work.  Now I stand corrected I think.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because num is a copy.
It's as if you were doing this:

```
int i = numbers[0];
i = 0;
```

You wouldn't expect that to change numbers[0], would you?

Answer (score 0):

Because *int* is a [value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and is passed to your extension method as a value parameter. Thus a copy of `numbers` is passed to your `ForEach` method. The values stored in the `numbers` array that is initialized in the `BasicForEachTest` method are never modified.

Check this [article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) by Jon Skeet to read more on value types and value parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I am not claiming that the code in this answer is useful, but (it works and) I think it illustrates what you need in order to make your approach work. The argument must be marked `ref`. The BCL does not have a delegate type with `ref`, so just write your own (not inside any class):

```
public delegate void MyActionRef<T>(ref T arg);
```

With that, your method becomes:

```
public static void ForEach2<T>(this T[] list, MyActionRef<T> actionRef)
{
  if (actionRef == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("actionRef");

  for (int idx = 0; idx < list.Length; idx++)
  {
    actionRef(ref list[idx]);
  }
}
```

Now, remember to use the `ref` keyword in your test method:

```
numbers.ForEach2((ref int num) =>
{
    num = 0;
});
```

This works because it is OK to pass an array entry ByRef (`ref`).

If you want to extend `IList<>` instead, you have to do:

```
public static void ForEach3<T>(this IList<T> list, MyActionRef<T> actionRef)
{
  if (actionRef == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("actionRef");

  for (int idx = 0; idx < list.Count; idx++)
  {
    var temp = list[idx];
    actionRef(ref temp);
    list[idx] = temp;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps your understanding.

Note: I had to use `for` loops. In C#, in `foreach (var x in Yyyy) { /* ... */ }`, it is not allowed to assign to `x` (which includes passing `x` ByRef (with `ref` or `out`)) inside the loop body.